# Some images wont load on internet explorer 10 & 9 & 8

Tags: image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

When i load my website on IE10/9/8 some images wont load.

and if i reload the page, the previous images loads perfectly, but some other images wont load.

And if i remove the browser cache, and refresh the page, same thing. some images load and other w'ont load. you can also see that problem in the portfolio page

thanks

Comment: don't use internet explorer, it sucks brah

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the webpage in alternative browsers? I'm loading it in Google Chrome and all the images load perfectly fine. Internet Explorer utilities your graphics card as well as your processor to load images to make it faster, which might be totally irrelevant for this question but perhaps your graphics card/processor is causing you issues?

If it's working in other browsers, then use them as opposed to Internet Explorer. It will be a bug with their browser and it's compatibility with whatever system you're using. It's the worst browser to use in all honesty.